# Assigning a function as another function's property

Tags: javascript, function, properties, scope

Why does this work:

```
var myFunction = function() {}

myFunction.printSomething = function() {
    console.log("This is something");
}

myFunction.printSomething();
```

While this doesn't? ("Identifier expected" problem)

```
var myFunction = function() {
    printSomething: function() {
        console.log("This is something");
    }
}

myFunction.printSomething();
```

Am I actually successfully creating a new printSomething property of the myFunction function object in the first example? I was expecting both to work given that functions are supposedly objects in javascript. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: The second example doesn't work because that's not meaningful JavaScript syntax. Functions are indeed objects, but the `{ }` after the function header are for the code block, not an object initializer.

Answer (score 1):

The second example would work if you did this:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    return {
        printSomething: function() {
            console.log("This is something");
        }
    }
}

myFunction().printSomething();
```

The syntax that you had doesn't work. You can't just have `printSomething: function(){};` hanging out in the open in the middle of a function like that. You could have `var printSomething = function(){}`, or you can do what I did and return an object, where `printSomething: function(){}` is a part of that object

Comment: this was insightul. But I think you meant `myFunction().printSomething()` in that function call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object from the function and that you can call as expected.

Please check the below snippet that I have created for a better understanding.

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  return {
    printSomething: function() {
        console.log("This is something");
    }
  };
}

myFunction().printSomething();
```

Comment: It's not a JSON object. It's just an object.

Comment: Ya sorry, my mistake. Will update the answer. :-) Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pointy for pointing my in the right direction in his comment.

Yes, functions are indeed objects, and they can contain properties just like any other object.

However, in the second example, the block of code in `{ }` are what is executed when myFunction is called, and not its definition as an object.

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // 'printSomething:' can't just be hanging like that!
    printSomething: function() {
        console.log("This is something");
    }
}

myFunction.printSomething();
```